# Can I ignore a div when using transparentcy?

Tags: html, css

can I ignore a div when using transparency?
    imgur.com/a/gvf1ek3   //not enough reputation :(

I wanted to make the gray area transparent, so you could see the gradient threw.

Also have you got any advice, how I can make my transition smoother?
I'm new to programming.
Thanks in advance

```css
body {
  background-color: white
}

.timelineElementInnen {
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.timelineElementMitte {
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: gray;
  _background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  transition: 1000ms;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0px
}

.timelineElementMitte:hover {
  padding: 25px;
  border-radius: 75px;
}

.timelineElementAußen {
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  transition: 1000ms;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 50px;
}

.timelineElementAußen:hover {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 25px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="margin: 100px; background: linear-gradient(to right,red, gray); width: 400px; height: 400px;">
    <div style="padding: 100px">
      <div class="timelineElementAußen">
        <div class="timelineElementMitte">
          <div class="timelineElementInnen"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot ignore a div, but a simple workaround in your case would be to not use a background-color on the middle div at all, and then color the outer element's **border** instead of its background color:

- `.timelineElementMitte`: Change background to `background-color: none` (or just remove it).
- `.timelineElementAußen`: Remove `background-color`, add `border: 0 solid white`
- `.timelineElementAußen:hover`: Remove `padding`, add `border-width: 25px`

```css
body {
  background-color: white
}

.timelineElementInnen {
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.timelineElementMitte {
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: none; /* replaces background-color: gray; */
  transition: 1000ms;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.timelineElementMitte:hover {
  padding: 25px;
  border-radius: 75px;
}

.timelineElementAußen {
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 50px;
  transition: 1000ms;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0 solid white; /* replaces background-color: white; */
  margin: 50px;
}

.timelineElementAußen:hover {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border-width: 25px; /* replaces padding: 25px; */
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="margin: 100px; background: linear-gradient(to right,red, gray); width: 400px; height: 400px;">
    <div style="padding: 100px">
      <div class="timelineElementAußen">
        <div class="timelineElementMitte">
          <div class="timelineElementInnen"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```